# New to frq analysis in python, Scipy rfft

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently moved from MATLAB to python since pyhton is better suited for the current project. Since my thesis is in biomechanics, i find myself in deep water as i am not that experienced in either python or this type of analysis.

My function looks like this:

```
def PolarFFT(data):                      
    L = len(data)
    R = np.zeros((data.shape))   
    R = sp.fftpack.rfft(data)     
    R = np.abs(R)
    R = R[1:-1]    
    n = R.size
    ts = 1/fs
    f = sp.fftpack.rfftfreq(L,ts)
    f = f[1:-1]

    outputfft = R
    outputfft[:,-1] = f

    return outputfft

accWindfrq = PolarFFT(accWind)
```

This is my best shot so far, and it does not work as intended. It seems to just output the raw data in another scaling.
The idea is to have a output which is a Lx4 matrix where col 1=x, 2=y, 3=z and 4=frequency bins.

Is there anyone who can help me with this? Or point me in the right direction? Maybe what i have done above is not even possible? ANY comments and help is very much appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `accWind` is an Lx3 array.
`R = np.zeros((data.shape))` doesn't do anything, as it will be replaced. The next line points `R` at the new data rather than copying it into `R`.
`R = sp.fftpack.rfft(data)` should be `R = sp.fftpack.rfft(data, axis=0)`. By default it fourier transforms over the last axis.
`outputfft[:,-1] = f` doesn't concatenate the arrays. It overwrites the last column. You can use one of:

```
outputfft = np.concatenate((R, f), axis=1)
# or
outputfft = np.hstack((R, f))
# or
outputfft = np.empty((f.size, 4), dtype='c')
outputfft[:, :-1] = R
outputfft[:, -1] = f
```

I only included the last one because I thought that's what you were going for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! the accwind is actually Lx4 where no4 col is a time var that is not needed an therefore i overwrite it with the frequencies(is this causing a problem?). Should i slice out the time before the fft and then use one of your suggested methods instead? The 'axis=0' solved one problem, thanks!

on another note, i get amplitudes of up to 80.000 and that does not sound right for accelerometer data. What can i have done wrong?

Comment: I tried to attach a picture of my fft plot, but the technicalities of stackoverflow is still quite new to me, so i failed in this.  There is one really big peak around 5 hz of 80.000. Following peaks maxes out at 18.000 and flattens out just around 50 hz.

Comment: Ah. In that case you can ignore everything I said about concatenation. I thought you were going for a Matlab `end+1` type of thing. The only other thing I can think of is a `dt` factor between discrete and continuous Fourier transforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

"The only other thing I can think of is a dt factor between discrete and continuous Fourier transforms"

Can you elaborate on this? Should i do both kind of analysis?

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia pages for the [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition) and [discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) transforms, and approximate the integral with a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), you'll see that the two differ by a factor of `dt`, the time-step, which I think is `ts` in your code. This does depend on whether your intuition is for the continuous or discrete case, but I'd try multiplying your answer by `ts` and see if it fits your intuition better.